# Use wildcard in WHERE clause in MySQL prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the following MySQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field`=?;";
$prepare = $connect -> prepare( $sql );
$prepare -> bind_param( "i" , $value );
$value = $_GET["value"];
//etc.
```

However, "not filtered" is an option. Is there a way to pass a wildcard into the statement, like:

```
if ( ! isset ( $_GET["value"] ) ) $value = SOME_WILDCARD_INDICATOR;
```

...or do I have to have a whole separate code block for an unfiltered query?

Comment: What? Do you want all of the rows for the table? Just drop the `WHERE` clause. `SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: You could add some logic to extend the query to the WHERE clause prior to preparing.

Comment: If I just drop the `WHERE` clause then `bind_param()` returns an error because there's no placeholder in the query.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: You mean something like `WHERE 0=?` and `$value = 0;` if `$_GET["value"]` is `null`? Mmh... Clever.

Comment: How about simple writing `if (!isset($_GET['value'])) { $stmt = $connect->query('SELECT * FROM table'); } else { $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?'); $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);} $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();`... that'd be the easiest thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you said "add some logic," @Jay-Blanchard, I thought you meant this, and it works perfectly:

```
$filter = " WHERE 0=?";
$value = 0;

if ( isset ( $_GET["value"] ) )
{   
    $filter = " WHERE `field`=?";
    $value = $_GET["value"];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`" . $filter . ";";
$prepare = $connect -> prepare( $sql );
$prepare -> bind_param( "i" , $value );

//etc.
```

Good inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you want to only add the where condition if the value exists.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$value = $_GET['value'];

if ($value)
{
  $sql .= " WHERE `field` = ?"
}

$query = $db->prepare ($sql);

if ($value)
{
  $query->bind_param ('i', $value);
}
```

Comment: This looks a little like PDO. I'm using MySQLi. Does this work in MySQLi? I don't recognise `bindValue()`; is this `bind_param()`?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right - a force of habit, i do apologise! Will edit as per your original query.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a little logic -

```
$value = $_GET["value"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
if (isset($value)) {
    $sql .= "WHERE `field`=?";
    $prepare -> bind_param( "i" , $value );
}
$sql .= ";";
```

Comment: Where would `$prepare = $connect -> prepare( $sql );` go?

Comment: Your usage of the OOP MySQLi is a little confusing because I don't have the connection information, so it would be hard to say. If you edit your OP with a little more information I can help you with this.